# Newbie Linq to SQL correct way to map to POCO?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

With a fair bit of embarrassment, I wish to ask / determine the best way to map a Linq-To-SQL query to a POCO. I am not in a position to use EF at the moment, so sticking with Linq-To-SQL.

As of now, I have a simple class as follows:

```
public class DiaryEvent
{
    public Int64 ID { get; set; }
    public string ResourceCalendarID { get; set; }
    public string EventTitle { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string ResourceColour { get; set; }
    public bool AllDay { get; set; }
}
```

My Linq-to-SQL (LTS) query is as follows:

```
DataClassesDataContext db = new DataClassesDataContext();
var qry =
         from b in db.bookings
         select b
```

Because the database table bookings isn't/can't be created exactly as my DiaryEvent class, I am currently iterating over b like:

```
List<DiaryEvent> EventList = new List<DiaryEvent>();
foreach (booking item in qry)
{
    EventList.Add(new DiaryEvent
    {
        AllDay = false,
        Description = item.bookingDescription,
        ID = item.bookingID,
        StartDate = (DateTime)item.startDate,
        EndDate = (DateTime)item.endDate,
        EventTitle = item.bookingName,
        Location = item.bookingLocation,
        ResourceCalendarID = item.resourceID.ToString(),
        ResourceColour = item.bookingColour.Trim()
    });
}
```

This maps my data correctly, however I am not sure if this is the fastest/most correct way to achieve this?
I would be grateful for any feedback as to confirming if the above technique is acceptable, or if there are ways to improve upon that?

P.S:  In fairness, there isn't going to be massive amounts of data to retrieve.. maybe a few hundred rows in any given circumstance.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe AutoMapper could help, but ... If what you have works...

Comment: There's an issue for AutoMapper regarding that http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/stop-using-automapper-in-your-data-access-code so you have to decide whether you want to use it or not.

Comment: Hey thanks guys.. I had heard of automapper.. so thanks for pointing out, and @Leo Luis, thanks for that article.. well written - not read all of it yet, but great to understand the context of "why" to either use or not use something.. so thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless I've misunderstood something, you could simplify your code to something like this:

```
var EventList = (from b in db.bookings
                select new DiaryEvent
                {
                    AllDay = false,
                    Description = b.bookingDescription,
                    ID = b.bookingID,
                    StartDate = (DateTime)b.startDate,
                    EndDate = (DateTime)b.endDate,
                    EventTitle = b.bookingName,
                    Location = b.bookingLocation,
                    ResourceCalendarID = b.resourceID.ToString(),
                    ResourceColour = b.bookingColour.Trim()
                }).ToList();
```

The result is virtually the same but it saves you having to use the foreach.

Comment: Thanks John!  I'm hooked up to do a few plural-sight courses shortly - just time has been one of those things!  so that example is exactly what I was looking for - had a feeling it had to be something like that, and actually the article @Leo Luis posted (above, actually about automapper/not to use) showed an example like yours, so thanks for confirming, much appreciated - anything that makes the code easier to read / cut down on typing is a good thing!

Comment: @DavidSheardown Glad it helped!  Hope the courses work out well for you. :)